# Certification Test Suspended - Image Mismatch - What should I do?

Tags: certification

I sat for the ADM 201 certification, due to technical issues i couldn't complete the test, i had a chat with the online support team, he relaunched my test and when i clicked on relaunch, it asked me for the photo, and i took the photo, it said a photo mismatch and the test got suspended (this is ridiculous, how can it be a mismatch) and it says to contact the program manager for information on rescheduling the exam.

I opened a case and yet to get a reply from them. Is there anything else I should do? How long does it take to get the rescheduled date. Thanks.

Comment: I've tweeted to SalesforceU on Twitter about your problem. https://twitter.com/dhoechst/status/509158799572103168 Maybe that will get someone's attention.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Hope they would look into it at the earliest and do the needful as I was expecting a reply from them during their working hours. I again lodged another case quoting my case number. I hope it doesn't confuse them.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue today as Avinash. My exam is suspended. I am frustrated not being able to take the exam after preparing. I dont know when I would get a response from them. I also raised a case. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to opening a case you might consider the following supporting channels, first emailing certification@salesforce.com, and as @DanielHoechst mentioned sending a tweet to @SalesforceU. I've worked with certification from time to time, and things can get very busy during some exam periods, so please be patient if they don't get back to you right away.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. I appreciate your spontaneous reply. I will send an email to the supporting channel mentioned by you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ralph. 
I sent an email to certification@salesforce.com as mentioned by you, i got an automated reply with another case number. Now i have 3 case numbers for the same case. Hope the certification team doesn't get confused or get annoyed on me.

Comment: @Avinash, totally understand the frustration. I'm sure they're in process, but if you pass along some case numbers I can send along to a friend in certification to check that they're in progress. Although, just so you're aware the DEV 501 cert is getting graded right now (as well as the ADM 201), so it may not be the fastest response.

Comment: My Certification Case numbers 00064978, 00065205, 00065209. These are the case numbers i got for the response of my frustration. All the case numbers are for the same case, applied at different intervals. Thanks for your help Ralph.